# What is this “cyclic inheritance” called in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

I saw a code like this the other day:

```
type
    TcxGridTableControllerAccess = class (TcxGridTableController);

    TMycxGridDBTableView = class (TcxGridDBTableView)
    protected
        function GetViewDataClass: TcxCustomGridViewDataClass; override;
    end;

    TMycxGridViewData = class (TcxGridViewData)
    protected
        function GetFilterRowClass: TcxGridFilterRowClass; override;
    end;

    TMycxGridFilterRow = class (TcxGridFilterRow)
    protected
        procedure SetValue(Index: Integer; const Value: Variant); override;
    end;

    TcxGridDBTableView = class (TMycxGridDBTableView);
```

TMycxGridDBTableView inherited from TcxGridDBTableView that inherited from TMycxGridDBTableView. Searched for Cyclic Inheritance but only Java results.

What is this called?

Ps: I don't have the full buildable code with me.

Comment: For future reference: The proper behavior here is to edit your previous question, not to simply create a new duplicate question. In this case, this one is much better, so I've closed the other one as the duplicate.

Comment: @Ken - only the titles are identical. The other question asks a totally different thing, which displays some code sample which cannot exist. By the time it was evident that the asker couldn't provide a proper sample, it was answered several times. Hence the question with the correct sample here...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: See the revision history of the other question. They're the same question. The OP got downvotes there, and re-asked the same question here with slightly more information and the code that should have been used (and at one time existed) in the other post. Rob even wrote basically the same answer there.

Comment: @Ken - I know the revision, the first version is the exact same version as it is now.

Comment: @Sertac: Which makes them duplicates. If Rob could write the same (almost word-for-word) answer to both of them, they're duplicates regardless of exact phrasing of the question. A question asking *How do I add the two integer variables C and D* is a duplicate of *How do I add two integer vars A and B*; they're not different because the variables are named differently.

Comment: @Ken - Nope, the first version of that question is the same with the third (last) version of *that* question. The 2nd version, which was a different question, is now here.

Comment: @Sertac: The **intent** and **question** are the same, whether the code is identical or not. You're arguing semantics, I'm stating the facts. (And since the previous question makes no sense in it's current state, with code that cannot possibly exist, there's no point in keeping it open anyway.)

Comment: @Ken - Ok, what we disagree is I don't care intent at all. The question should take care asking what it intended to ask. People may answer without discovering actual intent - that's effort commited, the question should be maintained at that level than. I can see your point of view though, and I don't mind the other one being closed BTW, it will be deleted eventually.

Comment: @Sertac: Yes, the OP should ask the question they mean to ask, with actual realistic (and compilable) code. While I empathize with those who answered it, it doesn't change the value of the question itself, which with the code it contains is none IMO. But we can agree to disagree. :-)

Comment: @ken They are not dupes. As was discussed extensively at the other question. What a mess. This question was asked because I specifically asked for it to be asked. The code in the two questions is completely different. The question here is what Lucas *meant* to ask. The other question is what he *actually* asked. Two different questions.

Comment: @David: If Rob can copy/paste the same answer from the other post into this one and simply change variable or type names, it's a duplicate. The other should be closed as such. If you specifically asked for a duplicate to be posted, that's not my fault. If the poster asked something different than what they meant to ask, they should edit to ask the intended question. And when the best answer you can come up with for it is *The technical term is syntax error. This code is illegal.*, it clearly has no future value here.

Comment: @ken Read the bodies of the question. Are they the same? No they are not. Rob will remove his answer when it is unaccepted. Rob's answer at the other question actually answers this question as can be sent from the edit histories. Do bear in mind that the code here compiles and the code there is not legal. I don't think the other question is very good and it could be deleted. It is not a dupe of this though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you show is not *cyclic* inheritance. What happens is that `dxSample.TMycxGridDBTableView` inherits from a `TcxGridDBTableView` in another unit, probably `cxGridDBTableView.TcxGridDBTableView`. And `dxSample.TcxGridDBtableView` inherits from `dxSample.TMycxGridDBTableView`.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
type
  TcxGridTableControllerAccess = class(TcxGridTableController);

  { Note: this does NOT inherit from the TcxGridDBTableView defined  }
  { a little further on in the source. It inherits from the original }
  { DevEx TcxGridDBTableView.                                        }

  TMycxGridDBTableView = class(cxGridDBTableView.TcxGridDBTableView)
  protected
    function GetViewDataClass: TcxCustomGridViewDataClass; override;
  end;

  TMycxGridViewData = class(TcxGridViewData)
  protected
    function GetFilterRowClass: TcxGridFilterRowClass; override;
   end;

  TMycxGridFilterRow = class(TcxGridFilterRow)
  protected
    procedure SetValue(Index: Integer; const Value: Variant); override;
  end;

  TcxGridDBTableView = class(TMycxGridDBTableView);
```

So the hierarchy is:

```
cxGridDBTableView.TcxGridDBTableView
                 |
                 v
   dxSample.TMycxGridDBTableView
                 |
                 v
    dxSample.TcxGridDBTableView
```

So `dxSample.TMycxGrdiDBTableView` does **not** inherit from `dxSample.TcxGridDBTableView`, but from `cxGridDBTableView.TcxGridDBTableView` instead, so **there is no so called cyclic inheritance** there. The whole misunderstanding comes from the fact that the two classes in the different units have the same name and that the first declaration does not fully qualify the class it is inheriting from.

Now, if someone puts the unit `dxSample` after `cxridDBTableView` in his or her `uses` clause, then `dxSample.TCxGridDBTableView` is used, instead of the original DevEx class. This is called *interposing*.

When people want to modify the behaviour of the VCL and FireMonkey, it is not unusual to see interposer classes like

```
type
  TVCLClass = class(OriginalVCLUnit.TVCLClass)
    // modifications to the original TVCLClass
  end;
```

or

```
type
  TMyVCLClass = class(OriginalVCLUnit.TVCLClass)
    //
  end;

  TVCLClass = class(TMyVCLCLass);
```

The code you showed does the latter.

Answer (score 9):

The example code doesn't do what you think it does. You see `TMycxGridDBTableView` being defined as a descendant of `TcxGridDBTableView`, and then you see `TcxGridDBTableView`, defined as a descendant of `TcxGridDBTableView`.

However, the `TcxGridDBTableView` you see at the top is not the same `TcxGridDBTableView` that you see later. The first one refers to a class declared elsewhere, in some other unit. The next occurrence is declaring a *new* class in *this* unit that happens to have the same base name as the other unit's class.

This technique is known as an **interposer class**. It's used to introduce a new `GetViewDataClass` method, but still end up with the same class name. The form that uses controls with that name will use the new version of the class instead of the original version. It's a way to customize a VCL control without having to compile and install a custom package.